# A JavaScript Rich Editor That Doesn't Convert Non-ASCII Text to Character Entities?

Tags: html, javascript, internationalization, text-editor

I am working on a site for Spanish speakers, and I am looking for a UTF-8 enabled JavaScript Rich Text Editor that preserves non-ascii characters as text, instead of entity encoding. That is, when I type the words "cañón" and "pingüino", I want the RTE to preserve the non-ascii characters as they are, not to encode them into "ca&ntilde;&oacute;n" and "ping&uuml;ino".

So far I have checked out CKEdit, MCEdit and Nicedit, and the three of them convert my text to entities.

Answer (score 1):

[TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com) supports multiple languages with their language packs:
http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Language

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can config ckeditor to preserves non-ascii characters as text:

http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.entities
http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/src/core_config.js.html